# Unable to click on compose button in Gmail using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

My code is:

```
public class LoginGmail{    
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException  {   
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:/selenium/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe"); 

     WebDriver fd= new ChromeDriver();
     fd.get("https://www.google.com/intl/en_in/gmail/about/");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        fd.manage().window().maximize();
        WebElement e1=fd.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/nav/div/a[2]"));
        e1.click();
        WebElement username = fd.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='identifierId']"));
        username.sendKeys("sharmi.paul87@gmail.com");

        WebElement username_click = fd.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='identifierNext']/content/span"));
        username_click.click();

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(fd,30);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@aria-label=\"Enter your password\"]")));
       WebElement password= fd.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@aria-label=\"Enter your password\"]"));
               password.sendKeys("pramilapaul");
        WebElement password_click = fd.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='passwordNext']/content"));
        password_click.click();
    /*    --------------------------*/
        //fd.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'COMPOSE')]")).click();

        //WebElement button=fd.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@id,':ir')]"));
        //WebElement buttton=fd.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@gh='cm']"));*/
        //WebElement button=fd.findElement(By.cssSelector(".aic div[role='button']"));
 //  button.click();
```

HTML code:

COMPOSE

in the above" /*--*/"  any xpath  is not working.
Can anyone help in this? The xpaths are showing unable to locate element or compound classes are prohibited errors.

Comment: Add HTML code, So we can check Xpath locator

Comment: First of, "in the above /--/" is not a useful pointer to a block of code. Tell us what exactly isn't working. Second, yout question is missing [mcve]. Without HTML code to match your script against the script itself is completely useless. See this: http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Comment: <div class="T-I J-J5-Ji T-I-KE L3" role="button" tabindex="0" gh="cm" style="user-select: none;">COMPOSE</div>

Comment: @Sharmila I have written an answer, can you check it?

Comment: yes, but i replied.  its not working .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This xpath `"//div[@id=':ii']/div/div"` OR `.//div[normalize-space()='COMPOSE']` click the compose button for me.

Try this

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id=':ii']/div/div"));
```

Or

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[normalize-space()='COMPOSE']"));
```

---

I wrote the given below program in WATIR and checked it,it works, you can use the same locators in your program and you can execute it.

```
b.goto("www.gmail.com")
b.a(:text, "Sign In").click
b.element(:id, "identifierId").send_keys "sharmi.paul87@gmail.com"
b.element(:css, "#identifierNext > content.CwaK9 > span.RveJvd.snByac").click
b.element(:name, "password").send_keys "pramilapaul"
b.element(:css, "span.RveJvd.snByac").click
b.element(:xpath, "//div[@id=':ii']/div/div").click
```

Comment: But its not working  also for me. unable to locate  element.

Comment: @Sharmila I have updated another xpath, can you check it? Is your program leads you into the gmail page? Can you see the compose button when program terminates?

Comment: yes i checked. It shows unable to locate element. I successfully logged in into gmail but cant locate and click the compose button.

Comment: @Sharmila okay, I think that's because your program is not waiting for the element , include the implicit wait. Include this statement immediately after the driver variable (fd in yours)`driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`

Comment: @Sharmila can you accept my answer, there is a tic in top left of my answer , you can click there so that my answer would be accepted.